# Extending a measure on $\mathcal A$ to a measure on $\alpha(\mathcal A \cup \{C\})$ with $C \in \mathcal P(\Omega)\backslash \mathcal A$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am dealing with a  measure $\mu$ (to be precise a content, so it only has to be additive and not $\sigma$ - additive) which is defined on an algebra $\mathcal A$.

I would now like to show that I can extend $\mu$ on the algebra $\alpha(\mathcal A \cup \{C\})$ with $C \in \mathcal P(\Omega)\backslash \mathcal A$. I am not quite sure how to do this. I have been given a hint, however, which states that I should define: $$\mu(A\cap C) = \sup\{\mu(B): B\subseteq A\cap C, B \in \mathcal A\}$$

I am really stuck with this, since I do not know where to begin when trying to show additivity of this measure.. Any help is greatly appreciated!